# pandas regex match must be numbers and text

Tags: regex, pandas

I have the following series in pandas which I would like to scan with regex:

Sample data:

```
s1 = pd.Series(['PQ4Y-ab56-kj23', 'dont-pick-this', '23', 'dont-pick-these', np.NaN])
```

The objective is to identify **JUST** the first element in the series with regex

I have the following regex as a starter for ten, but it is identifying the first, second and third in the series.

```
s1.str.match('\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}')

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4      NaN
```

I  need the regex to be modified to take account of two factors which are causing problems:

1. It needs to exclusively identify four character strings - not a string that contains four or more characters
2. It needs to match only four character strings that contain BOTH letters and numbers and NOT select strings that are exclusively letters A-Z (or lowercase a-z)

Many thanks

Comment: `s1.str.match('^(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])(?=\D*\d)\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}$')` - make sure there is at least 1 letter and at least 1 digit

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew won't match either `'4ACE-ZXYZ-1a2b'` or `'4ABCD-ZXYZ-1a2b'`

Comment: @QuangHoang `4ABCD-ZXYZ-1a2b` should not be matched, it has 5 chars at the start.   `4ACE-ZXYZ-1a2b` [will be matched well](https://regex101.com/r/D56Usk/1).

Comment: The second string, my mistake. The first should not be match as `ZXYZ` does not contain a digit.

Comment: thanks Wiktor - works great. And I can extend to other w{} types. Brilliant!